# log4j2 RollingFile PatternLayout is not applied

Tags: log4j2

In the following `log4j2.xml` the rolling log file is being produced but without the PatternLayout being applied. What's going wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%style{%d{ISO8601}}{white} %highlight{%-5level }[%style{%t}{cyan}] %style{%M}{bright,yellow}: %msg%n%throwable" />
    </Console>

    <RollingFile name="RollingFile"
        fileName="./logs/Tests.log"
        filePattern="./logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/FixApi-%d{-dd-MMMM-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%style{%d{ISO8601}}{white} %highlight{%-5level }[%style{%t}{cyan}] %style{%M}{bright,yellow}: %msg%n%throwable" />
        <Policies>
            <!-- roll over daily and when file reaches 100 MegaBytes -->
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
    </Root>

    <Logger name="admin" level="info"></Logger>
</Loggers>
```